# Is the Chase-Lev Deque patent (US20070143326A1) still valid after Alice?

Tags: patentability, software

[US20070143326A1 - Dynamic Circular Work-Stealing Deque](https://www.google.com/patents/US20070143326) concerns a method of scheduling work on multiple threads by means of [work stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Work_stealing&oldid=746938916) using a resizable buffer. Since it was filed by David Chase and Yosef Lev, I assume it refers to their [Dynamic Circular Work Stealing Deque](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3771/77bb82105c35e6e26ebad1698a20688473bd.pdf) paper.

The techniques outlined in that paper represent the backbone of many open source multithreading libraries including Rust's [Rayon](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon). However, this patent appears to solely cover an abstract algorithm. I am just wondering if this patent is still valid after Alice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US2007014332A1 is a patent application. It has been granted as [US7346753B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US7346753B2/en) so it is currently a valid patent. It was issued in 2008 so the [Alice decision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International) came well after it. Whether Alice impacts the enforceability of US7346753B2 probably won't be known until Sun Microsystems (Oracle) tries to enforce it and if there is a resulting court case. I'm not a lawyer so I don't know if this has happened.